# Linear referencing using Oracle Spatial

Tags: oracle-spatial, linear-referencing

I wanted to Linear Reference a table in the Oracle database that has RouteID, Measurement From, and To in the fields using Oracle Spatial by referring to another Feature Class (Polyline) like it's done in ArcGIS Geoprocessing Tool. Is there a way to do it?
Further, develop that into creating geometries automatically when a record is added to the table.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_lrs_concepts.htm#SPATL060

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely possible. Here is an example.

First, let's take a table of US Interstates, that looks like this:

```
SQL> desc us_interstates
Name                                     Null?    Type
---------------------------------------- -------- --------------------
ID                                       NOT NULL NUMBER
INTERSTATE                                        VARCHAR2(35 CHAR)
GEOM                                              MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY
```

The geometries here are plain lines, without any measures. If you have those measures in your data, then you are all set. Here is one example line. Notice the coordinates are long/lat, but the LRS mechanism works the same way with projects coordinates:

```
SQL> select * from us_interstates where id = 174;

        ID INTERSTATE GEOM(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_ORDINATES)
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       174 I695/I83   SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, 4326, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-76.641953, 39.42001, -76.645142, 39.420681, -76.647324, 39.420731, -76.649948, 39.420269, -76.651787, 39.41972, -76.653732, 39.419079, -76.655586, 39.417912, -76.657516, 39.41663, -76.661118, 39.41399, -76.664093, 39.411396))

1 row selected.
```

To turn those lines into LRS lines (= with measures), you can do this:

```
declare
  status varchar2(32);
begin
  status := sdo_lrs.convert_to_lrs_layer('US_INTERSTATES','GEOM');
end;
/
commit;
```

This function will add measures to all of the points of the lines. The first measure of each line will be 0. The last measure will be the length of the line (in meters). All vertices on the line will be extended with measures. For example line 174 is now like this:

```
        ID INTERSTATE GEOM(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_ORDINATES)
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       174 I695/I83   SDO_GEOMETRY(3302, 4326, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-76.641953, 39.42001, 0, -76.645142, 39.420681, 284.535089, -76.647324, 39.420731, 472.511426, -76.649948, 39.420269, 704.216249, -76.651787, 39.41972, 873.901202, -76.653732, 39.419079, 1055.8826, -76.655586, 39.417912, 1261.49545, -76.657516, 39.41663, 1480.31431, -76.661118, 39.41399, 1907.0815, -76.664093, 39.411396, 2292.54789))
```

The geometry type `3302` indicates that each vertex now has 3 ordinates, and that the third ordinate contains the M (measure) for each vertex.

The vertices now are like this:

```
-76.641953, 39.420010, 0, 
-76.645142, 39.420681, 284.535089, 
...
-76.661118, 39.413990, 1907.0815, 
-76.664093, 39.411396, 2292.54789
```

Now, let's create the equivalent of your routes table. It looks like this:

```
create table us_road_conditions (
  id             number primary key,
  interstate     varchar2(35),
  from_measure   number,
  to_measure     number,
  condition      varchar2(6)
);
```

Each row represents a section of an interstate with a "road condition" flag. Some sample data:

```
insert into us_road_conditions values ( 1, 'I25',      0, 150000, 'good');
insert into us_road_conditions values ( 2, 'I25', 150000, 170000, 'poor');
insert into us_road_conditions values ( 3, 'I25', 170000, 340000, 'fair');
insert into us_road_conditions values ( 4, 'I25', 340000, 481426, 'good');

insert into us_road_conditions values ( 5, 'I70',      0, 300000, 'good');
insert into us_road_conditions values ( 6, 'I70', 300000, 450000, 'poor');
insert into us_road_conditions values ( 7, 'I70', 450000, 650000, 'good');
insert into us_road_conditions values ( 8, 'I70', 650000, 726930, 'fair');

insert into us_road_conditions values ( 9, 'I76',      0, 120000, 'poor');
insert into us_road_conditions values (10, 'I76', 120000, 200000, 'good');
insert into us_road_conditions values (11, 'I76', 200000, 240000, 'fair');
insert into us_road_conditions values (12, 'I76', 240000, 296381, 'good');

insert into us_road_conditions values (13, 'I225',     0,   9500, 'good');
insert into us_road_conditions values (14, 'I225',  9500,  19566, 'poor');
commit;
```

Now, I'm ready to do dynamic segmentation on that data. This is easily done using the SDO_LRS.CLIP_GEOM_SEGMENT() function:

```
select i.interstate,
       sdo_lrs.clip_geom_segment (
         i.geom,
         p.from_measure,
         p.to_measure) geom
from   us_interstates i,
       us_road_conditions p
where  i.interstate = p.interstate
and    p.condition = 'poor';
```

This query will clip out all the sections of interstates that are in a poor condition. You can do whatever you like with the result, for example, save it into a table. The result is like this (truncated to fit in the response)

```
        ID INTERSTATE GEOM(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_ORDINATES)
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        31 I225       SDO_GEOMETRY(3302, 4326, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-104.82859, 39.6827223, 9500, -104.82856, 39.693008, 10642.0098, -104.82888, 39.696762, 11059.7145, ... ))
        38 I25        SDO_GEOMETRY(3302, 4326, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-104.73076, 37.5730658, 150000, -104.73318, 37.576931, 150479.204, -104.73363, 37.577469, 150550.937, ... ))
       176 I70        SDO_GEOMETRY(3302, 4326, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-102.98675, 39.2736003, 300000, -102.98904, 39.273178, 300203.189, -102.99213, 39.27272, 300474.553,  ... ))
       188 I76        SDO_GEOMETRY(3302, 4326, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-105.0736, 39.7864, 0, -105.07269, 39.78656, 79.7815595, -105.0695, 39.78764, 378.10715, ... ))

4 rows selected.
```

The LRS feature has many other useful functions, including one to remove the measures from LRS lines, and return them back as regular 2D lines.

To read about LRS in Oracle, see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/lrs-linear-referencing-system-concepts.html#GUID-9793361B-6C73-41E1-8389-85D8788ED083). For the details about the APIs, see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/SDO_LRS-reference.html#GUID-38A5534F-0B2D-410B-8210-3DFFD4E4AE5B).